# Configuring Vagrantfile for multiple machine - Vagrant

Tags: linux, vagrant, virtual-machine, vagrantfile

I have setup a Virtual box with two VMs a) Ubuntu b) Windows 10. I have created vagrant boxes for each of these VMs from scratch. Each of the vagrant box runs good individually. But I want to launch both the VMs at once. So I created a Vagrantfile (shown below) with the help of this documentation: https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/multi-machine/

With the following Vagrantfile, the box declared first gets launched while the other doesn't. Is there any error in my Vagrantfile?
Any solutions, hints on how to fix this problem? How do I launch both the VMs?

-----------Vagrantfile---------------

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

 config.vm.define "linux" do |linux|
  linux.vm.box = "ubuntu"
  linux.vm.box_url = "/Users/xyz/Desktop/vagrant/linux_package.box"
end

 config.vm.define "win" do |win|
  win.vm.box = "Windows10"
  win.vm.box_url = "/Users/xyz/Desktop/vagrant/win_package.box"
  end

config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
v.gui = true
end

end
```

---

Output on terminal:

When linux machine is launched first, I get below message on terminal:

```
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

mkdir -p /vagrant
Stdout from the command:
Stderr from the command:
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Answer (score 0):

Logging in to the guest (through gui mode) and making sure the vagrant user was set up like so in `/etc/sudoers` with the fix :

```
vagrant ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Run `visudo` as root in order to edit this file.

Comment: I added the above line to /etc/sudoers file in linux machine. But still I get the same error: "The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

mkdir -p /vagrant

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified"